# SQL/PHP - created search form, how to return the data?

Tags: php, sql

Here's my form:

```
<form action="course-search.php" method="post">
    <Label>Select Subject ID: </label>
    <select name="results"> 
        <option>please chooses an id</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>18</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="Search" value="1">Search!</button>
</form>
```

SQL query I need to run to return the data:

```
SELECT title
FROM `course`
WHERE `id` =18(search options)
```

and then post the results on the same page?

I've been looking around for tutorials but can't find any that fit my situation. If someone could help or link to a tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your form to:

```
<form action="course-search.php" method="post">
    <Label>Select Subject ID: </label>
    <select name="results"> 
        <option value="-1">please chooses an id</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="Search" value="1">Search!</button>
</form>
```

Add this in your PHP script:

```
if(isset($_POST['results']) && $_POST['results'] != -1){
   $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
   $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT title FROM course WHERE `id`=?");
   $stmt->execute(array($_POST['results']));
   while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       echo $row['title'];
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. This runs fine without any errors. How my result isn't showing?

Comment: Sorted it. Wrong column name! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

On the same page you can get the data from the post form like this:

```
$resultchoice = $_POST['results'];
```

You then need to incorporate that into your mysql query. I like mysqli but it doesn't really matter what method you use.
First connect to the MySQL server:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("your_server","your_username","your_password", "your_database");
```

Then we need to query the database:

```
$query = "SELECT title FROM course WHERE id = " . $resultchoice;
$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$query);
$results = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Next we display the results:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
  {
  echo $row['title'];
  echo "<br>";
  }
```

Lastly, close the connection:

```
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: I've included my connect.php page in the top of the document already. So I'm getting an error with $results = mysqli_query($link, $query);
Should I remove the link from the top?

Comment: Could you attach connect.php? $link is the connection to the server so if you use a different variable name then you should change it to what you use.

Comment: Ok I've done that. 

I'm getting error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

on line: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results));

Comment: This means that php was expecting a sql result, but got a boolean. mysqli_query returns FALSE when the query fails. Your mysql query is failing. May I see you mysql error log? Also, can you add `vardump($results);` to your code? Thanks.

Comment: I posted the error, the rest of it is just the root and line no.

Comment: I am sorry, I misspelled var_dump in my previous post. What is the value of $results when you run the query?

It should be: `var_dump($results);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41374/discussion-between-tom-and-735tesla)